# How to change a single value in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have a data frame looks like this:

```
   Tm       elo_score
1  BRK      1500
2  GSW      1500
3  LAC      1500
4  LAL      1500
5  BOS      1500
```

I would like to change for example, `BRK` `elo_score` to `1000`, I tried `elo_score["Tm" == "BRK", "elo_score"] <- 1` but it is not working. May I know how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to extract the column

```
elo_score$elo_score[elo_score$Tm == "BRK"] <- 1000
```

---

```
"Tm" == "BRK"
```

does a comparison of two strings i.e. "Tm" with "BRK" and not the values of the column "Tm".  For that either `elo_scores[["Tm"]]` or `elo_scores$Tm` or `elo_scores[, "Tm"]` (if it is `data.frame` ) would work

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
elo_score[data.framename$Tm == "BRK", "elo_score"] <- 1
```

in which data.framename is the name of your dataframe object

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
transform(
  elo_score,
  elo_score = replace(elo_score, Tm == "BRK", 1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this (as other answers have shown).  There is even a built in editor.  Here are some approaches that have the same result:

```
> df
    Tm elo_score
1  BRK      1500
2  GSW      1500
3  LAC      1500
4  LAL      1500
5  BOS      1500
> df$elo_score[1] <- 1000   # data.frame access to column, numeric index
> df$elo_score[df$Tm=="BRK"] <- 1000  # data.frame access to column, logical index
> df[1,2] <- 1000   # Numeric row and column (same as matrix)
> df[df$elo_score=="BRK",2] <-1000  # Logical row, numeric column
> df <- edit(df)  # Change it in the editor window
```